# Cisco disables port on switch when configures linux bridge

Tags: cisco-catalyst, interface

I have a CentOS server plugged into a Cisco 3048.

I use nm-connection-editor to configure a virtual bridge interface, like I've done a thousand times before.

Every time I enable the bridge, the switch disables the interface.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Please post the configurations.

Comment: ... and the error logged on the switch when it disables the port.

Comment: let me guess. Are you having spanning-tree bpdu-guard enabled on the switch or the port? It looks like your linux box sends stp packets which is not supposed to be on the "client" port on the cisco switch.

Comment: Please post "show interface" of the interface in question and possibly "show int status err-dis". Further, as already requested, please post the configuration of the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was BPDUGuard as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have port-security limiting the number of MAC addresses on that switchport.

I'm not sure exactly what you're bridging and how it works, but if it is creating a virtual device with another MAC address, then your switchport port-security settings may be shutting down the port once it reaches a defined limit of MAC addresses for that port.

If this is the case, you could either increase the number of MAC addresses allowed (these could be set for static, dynamic, or sticky) or change the violation mode (protect, restrict, or shutdown are options) to something less militant.

Posting your config would be mighty helpful.

--
Chris

Comment: BPDUGuard might be more likely than port security.

Comment: Sounds very probable to me!